# How to avoid extra line feeds in MIME export?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, mime

I'm exporting MIME eMails with the following code:

```
    public String fromRawMime(final Session s, final Document doc) throws NotesException {
        final Stream notesStream = s.createStream();
        final MIMEEntity rootMime = doc.getMIMEEntity();

        // check if it is multi-part or single
        if (rootMime.getContentType().equals("multipart")) {
            this.printMIME(rootMime, notesStream);
        } else {
            // We can just write the content into the
            // Notes stream to get the bytes
            rootMime.getEntityAsText(notesStream);
        }

        // Write it out
        notesStream.setPosition(0);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out.append(notesStream.read());
        notesStream.close();

        notesStream.recycle();
        rootMime.recycle();

        return out.toString();
    }

    // Write out a mime entry to a Stream object, includes sub entries
    private void printMIME(final MIMEEntity mimeRoot, final Stream out) throws NotesException {
        if (mimeRoot == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Encode binary as base64
        if (mimeRoot.getEncoding() == MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY) {
            mimeRoot.decodeContent();
            mimeRoot.encodeContent(MIMEEntity.ENC_BASE64);
        }

        out.writeText(mimeRoot.getBoundaryStart(), Stream.EOL_NONE);
        mimeRoot.getEntityAsText(out);
        out.writeText(mimeRoot.getBoundaryEnd(), Stream.EOL_NONE);

        if (mimeRoot.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("multipart")) {
            // Print preamble if it isn't empty
            final String preamble = mimeRoot.getPreamble();
            if (!preamble.isEmpty()) {
                out.writeText(preamble, Stream.EOL_NONE);
            }

            // Print content of each child entity - recursive calls
            // Include recycle of mime elements
            MIMEEntity mimeChild = mimeRoot.getFirstChildEntity();
            while (mimeChild != null) {
                this.printMIME(mimeChild, out);
                final MIMEEntity mimeNext = mimeChild.getNextSibling();
                // Recycle to ensure we don't bleed memory
                mimeChild.recyle();
                mimeChild = mimeNext;
            }
        }
    }
```

The result contains one empty line for each line. Including the content that gets added using `getEntityAsText`. What am I missing to get rid of the extra lines?

Answer (score 1):

The email RFCs require the use of CRLF to terminate text lines.

You are using EOL_NONE, so the writeText method isn't adding anything to the text, but apparently both the CR and LF are being treated as newlines in your output. You may want to try using out.writeText with EOL_PLATFORM instead.

Comment: out.append(notesStream.read()); doesn't take a EOL* parameter and that's my main issue.

Comment: I meant: getEntityAsText(out) doesn't take EOL* parameters - and there's the trouble

Answer (score 0):

The devils is in the details...

the `printMIME` function works just fine. Changing the EOL didn't have an impact. However I added EOL_PLATFORM later on for the final result to separate the headers from the content.

The offending code is this:

```
    notesStream.setPosition(0);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    out.append(notesStream.read());
    notesStream.close();
```

Turns out that it seems to interpret whatever was in the MIME as 2 line feeds. So the code needs to be changed to:

```
    notesStream.setPosition(0);
    String out  = notesStream.readText();
    notesStream.close();
```

so instead of a `OutputStream` I needed a `String` and instead of `read()` I needed `readText()`. Now working happily in my "project castle"